# Is there a way to generate blocks of statements with iterating variables in Python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm programming a little game with pygame and have to load and process a bunch of images. Each time I have to assign the loading function to a variable,  which is later being used to show the image on the screen, and each time a few variables in the assignment vary.

```py
one = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "one.png")).convert() # loading the image
one = pygame.transform.scale(one, (100, 100)) # scale image to size (100, 100)
one.set_colorkey(WHITE)                       # call a pygame function

two = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "two.png")).convert()
two = pygame.transform.scale(two, (100, 100))
two.set_colorkey(WHITE)
```

Later on i have to call a pygame function at each frame to show the image.

```py
window.blit(one, (30, 70))      # shows image 'one' at position x = 30, y = 70
window.blit(two, (30, 190))
```

I thought about writing a function which iterates over a list containing the required variable names and positions, but I assume I still have to assign this function to every variable I need (for example, see below).

```py
def load_and_scale(name):
    name = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, f"{name}.png")).convert()
    name = pygame.transform.scale(name, (100, 100))
    name.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    return name

one = load_and_scale("one")
```

But isn´t there a way to make it even briefer? A function which gets the names from a list and returns the variable name which is equal to some function.
I don´t want to assign this every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given code-

```
def load_and_scale(name):
    name = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, f"{name}.png")).convert()
    name = pygame.transform.scale(name, (100, 100))
    name.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    return name

one = load_and_scale(one)

window.blit(one, (30, 70))      # shows image 'one' at position x = 30, y = 70
window.blit(two, (30, 190))
```

Imagine-

```
loaded_images = []
for name, blit_args in image_names:
    loaded_images.append(load_and_scale(name), blit_args)

for loaded_image, blit_args in loaded_images:
    window.blit(loaded_image, blit_args)
```

You don't need an actual local variable for every object, store them in a collection.

Comment: load_and_scale returns None

Comment: Sure, fixed that, but that was obviously a typo in the question and not the issue they were looking for help with...

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with just doing the obvious thing : returning the value ?

```
def load_and_scale(name):
    img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, f"{name}.png")).convert()
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (100, 100))
    img.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    return img


one = load_and_scale("one")
two = load_and_scale("two")
```